# How to parse data from a UIViewController having 2 CollectionViews with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How do I parse data from a UIViewController having 2 different UICollectionViews?
I have 2 UICollectionViews in on UIViewController I have been able to pull the data from the server to the views and its displayed but i'm having trouble parsing it to the next screens.

I have tired this using didSelectItemAt and performSegue but it can't parse the data to the other screen

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if collectionView == self.categoryView {
            let categoryViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CategoryListViewController") as! CategoryListViewController
            categoryViewController.self.selectedC = self.category[indexPath.row]
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(categoryViewController, animated: true)

        } else if collectionView == self.featuredView {
            self.selectedPro = self.property[indexPath.row]
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDet", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "showCat"{
            let categoryController = segue.destination as! CategoryListViewController
            categoryController.selectedC = self.selectedC
        }
        else {
            let detailViewController = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
            detailViewController.selectedPro = self.selectedPro
        }


    }
```

I'm expected to parse data to the second screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Is the Solution

```
@IBOutlet weak var categoryView: UICollectionView!
let collectionViewAIdentifier = "catCell"
var category = [Category]()

@IBOutlet weak var featuredView: UICollectionView!
let collectionViewBIdentifier = "feaCell"
var property = [Property]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading...")

    categoryView.delegate = self
    categoryView.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(categoryView)

    featuredView.delegate = self
    featuredView.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(featuredView)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)     -> Int {
    var count:Int?
    // Category Collection View
    if collectionView == self.categoryView {count = category.count}

    //Property Collection View
    if collectionView == self.featuredView {count =  property.count}
    return count!
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)     -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // Category Collection View
    if collectionView == self.categoryView {
        let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:     collectionViewAIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell

        let cat: Category
        cat = category[indexPath.row]

        cellA.homId.text = cat.idd

        cellA.homName.text = cat.name


        //idCat = cat.idd!
        return cellA
    }
        //Property Collection View
    else {
        let cellB = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:     collectionViewBIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FeaturedCollectionViewCell

        let pro: Property
        pro = property[indexPath.row]

        cellB.proId.text = pro.idd
        cellB.proName.text = pro.name

        return cellB
    }

}

//Parsing data to next screen
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // Category Collection View parsing data
    if segue.identifier == "showCat" {
        let categoryDetailVC = segue.destination as! CategoryListViewController
        let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
        let indexPath = self.categoryView.indexPath(for: cell)
        let categoryId = category[(indexPath?.row)!].idd
        categoryDetailVC.idString = categoryId
    }

        //Property Collection View parsing data
    else if segue.identifier == "showDet" {
        let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
        let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
        let indexPath = self.featuredView.indexPath(for: cell)
        let detailId = property[(indexPath?.row)!].idd
        detailVC.idProString = detailId
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using two different collection views? Why don't you just create two different cells? That way you can easily do an if let in the didSelect which type of cell has been tapped and pass the data on?

Comment: both have different data from the server and one is vertical and another has a horizontal scroll like instagram home layout with stories and feed

Comment: why don't you then have two different subclasses of UIView. Which both have their own collection views and collection view delegates and a dedicated property datasource. In the parent view controller you can easily in viewDidLoad viewA.datasource = datasource A and viewB.datasource = datasourceB.